# Should I ask a question if I am already highly suspicious of the source?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Someone linked [this article](http://inhabitat.com/its-official-cell-phones-are-killing-bees/) on facebook today. Looking at it I think it is very likely bunk (also called woo, apparently?), and not just because it links the Daily Mail as its one-and-only source.

Should I, in an effort to combat the internet's ignorance, post a question here so someone with more free-time/knowledge than I can confirm my suspicions, or would that be considered . . . impolite?

Comment: Uuhiii, on the Daily Mail page someone even uses this phony Albert Einstein quote, ["If the bees disappeared from the face of the earth, man would have no longer than 4 years to live"](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1480/would-man-have-only-have-four-years-of-life-left-if-there-were-no-bees), ts ts.

Comment: @Martin: And that quote isn't from Einstein.

Comment: @Borror0: Yes, that what I meant with "phony".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're genuinely interested in the answer, go ahead and ask it.

Worst case, you make us debunk a false claim therefore making the Internet a better place. Best case, you realize you were wrong to dismiss it and now possess the correct information.

Comment: The latter's happened to me more than once!